# computing probability of pairing

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Alice has $n$ pairs of socks with $n$ colors ranging in shades of grey enumerated from $1$ to $n$. She takes the socks out of the drier and pairs them randomly. We will assume in each pair,the right and the left socks are identical.

Assume that Alice finds the pairing acceptable if all the socks are paired correctly.
Show that the probability of this event is:

$$ \frac{2^nn!}{(2n)!}$$

I have this question in one of my classes but I think what we are asked to prove is wrong. I think the probability that the pairing is acceptable is $\frac{1}{n!}$. Maybe I am missing something and making a fool of myself. Need some help!

Comment: When you found this discrepancy between your answer and the book's, naturally you checked the simplest case $n=2$ in detail, counting the pairings by hand to see which formula gave the right answer. Since you are asking the question, I assume you got probability $1/2$ for that case. I think you must have counted wrong. Please show your work: how many pairings did you count (list them), how many of them were correct pairings?

Comment: When I tried that myself for $n=2$, I came up with $3$ pairings; of course only $1$ was correct, so the probability is $1/3$. Evidently you only found $2$ pairings. Which ones were they?

Comment: Judging from the facts you have given us there are more colours than there are socks please put more detail in your question.

Comment: The question assumes you can't tell the difference between right and left socks. So here was my mistake. If you could tell the difference between the left and the right socks the answer would be $\frac{1}{n!}$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{2^nn!}{(2n)!}&=\frac{(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)\ldots(4)(2)}{(2n)!}\\\\
&=\frac1{(2n-1)(2n-3)\ldots(3)(1)}\\\\
&=\frac1{2n-1}\cdot\frac1{2n-3}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac11\;.
\end{align*}$$

There are $2n$ socks in the drier. She pulls one out, leaving $2n-1$ socks in the drier. Exactly one of those $2n-1$ socks matches the one in her hand, so the probability that she matches it is $\frac1{2n-1}$. Suppose that she’s lucky enough to do so. She now has $2n-2$ pairs of socks in the drier. She pulls one out, leaving $2n-3$ socks, one of which matches the sock in her hand, so her probability of getting a match on the second pair, given that she got a match on the first pair, is $\frac1{2n-3}$. I expect that you can see how to finish it from here. (Properly speaking it should be an induction argument.)

Comment: Alternatively, the probability is the reciprocal of the number of pairings, which is $\binom{2n}{2,2,\dots,2}/n!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$.

Answer (score 1):

The question assumes you can't tell the difference between right and left socks.
So there are $2n-1$ possible socks to match with the first sock, not $n$.